# Where is installed ventoy on the USB flash drive?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, files-folders, ventoy

Since months ago through Windows 10 I have installed `ventoy` on a USB flash drive to storage and boot some `.iso` files for installation purposes about Linux in other laptops. It works fine as expected. Even more, ventoy was upgraded few times in peace too.

My doubt and reason of this post, where is installed ventoy on the USB flash drive?

In Windows 10 if through `git bash` I go to the USB flash drive and is executed the `ls -als` command does not appear something hidden to observe about `ventoy` itself, for example I expected to see `.ventoy` or something similar. Same behavior with the `Windows Explorer` settings to about to show/view everything hidden (even the *operating system files*).

Comment: where did you get `ventoy`? ... did you check for multiple partitions on the USB flash drive?

Comment: From here: https://github.com/ventoy/Ventoy - AFAIK there is nothing about partitions

Comment: please update the question ... comments are not for updating the question

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 distinct partitions.

Ventoy is essentially a modified GRUB.

It installs in a small partition - VTOYEFI - (just 34MB in the USB stick I'm using) leaving the remaining space as an exFAT partition where you save the ISOs and anything else.